# React + Express (endpoint 404)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, endpoint

I get a 404 error on the client. Maybe someone knows what the problem is? I found information that you need to remove **node_modules** and **package-lock**, do `npm i` and everything will work. But it didn't work for me

Server: **index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const users = require('./routes/users.js')

app.use('/api/users', users);

app.listen(1234);

console.log('Server has been started on port 1234...')
```

**users.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {

  res.json([
    {
      username: 'User 1',
      age: 26
    },
    {
      username: 'User 2',
      age: 22
    }
  ])

});

module.exports = router;
```

**Client Component**:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/api/users')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(users => {
            this.setState({ users: users })
        });
}
```

**package.json**

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:1234"
```

Comment: If you look in the network panel, is the request correctly using your proxy setting and going to `http://localhost:1234/api/users`? What do you get if you go to that endpoint in your browser?

Comment: If I go to http://localhost:1234/api/users , I see this line
[{"username":"User 1","age":26},{"username":"User 2","age":22}]

Answer (score 0):

If you put this in the wepack, it works

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    proxy: {
        '/': {
            target: 'http://localhost:1234'
        },
    }
},
```